# Get a href Title and change on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a series of links set in an image gallery and I need a way to display the color to the user. Currently the color name is stored in the a href title of the link to the image in the gallery.

```
<div class="select-option swatch-wrapper selected" data-attribute="pa_luxcraft-2" data-value="redblack">
<a href="#" style="width:32px;height:32px;" title="Red/Black" class="swatch-anchor"><img src="/ay/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Center-Table-Red-Black-32x32.jpg" alt="thumbnail" class="wp-post-image swatch-photopa_luxcraft-2_ swatch-img" width="32" height="32" data-pin-nopin="true"></a>
</div>
```

In this case it is Red/Black for the color

Each time an image is clicked it gets assigned the class of "selected"

I know I can get the title with a simple variable of

```
var title = $(this).attr('title');
```

But I am unsure of how to get it when the class of selected is applied.

Comment: do you mean `$(this).hasClass('selected')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included a couple of examples to help get you started.

```
<div class="displayToUser"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("a").click (function () {
    $(document).css("background",$(this).attr("title"));  //set's background to color, just to let you know how to do that.
    $(this).attr("title","new title"); //changes title if that's what you want
    $(".displayToUser").html(
        $(this).attr("title")
    ); // sets an element to show the contents of title, just so that you know how to do that
    $(this).hasClass("selected"); //if you want to check to see if it has the class selected
    $(this).addClass("selected"); //to add the class selected, if that's what you're looking for.
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var color;

if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
   color = $(this).attr('title');
}

and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var valueoftitle = $('.selected')[<your_index>].attr('title');
```

Edit:

With `$('.selected')` you get a array back with all the elements with class .selected. Then you can access those elements with the square brackets with the index of the element that you want to access. After that you have the element and you can do with it whatever you want, like in this example: `.attr('title')`, which would give you back the value of the attribute 'title'. You can use this in any way possible like a for loop, foreach loop or just as inline with an index.

Comment: Some context or explanation would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the selected class is applied when the image is clicked. Assuming you have a click handler bound to the image, you could pickup the title attribute from the parent link with `$(this).parent('a').attr('title')`